# jdbc connection fails while running the program from jar file

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jar, connection, deadlock

I've got an application, where I use a JDBC connection. When I run it from the Eclipse environment, there's no problem with anything, neither with connection.
But, when I pack it into executable jar file, and run it from command line, while calling the line

```
DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

with correct credentials, the application gets frozen. (With wrong login attempt everything is ok - the SQLServerException is thrown).
I tried to create the jar file with different library choices, but the result is the same.

Can anyone help?

I use sqljdbc4.jar library

Constructor of my Database class:

```
public Database(String url, String user, String password) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    System.out.println("forname");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    System.out.println("get connection");
}
```

After correct login no Exception is thrown and "get connection" string is not printed out (only "forname" string is printed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Java 6 Update 29? If so Update to Java 6 Update 30 or higher (preferably the latest: Update 32). There was a bug in that Java version which caused the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver to hang.

Answer (score 0):

"frozen"?  Are you catching an Exception with an empty catch block?

I'll bet the JDBC driver JAR is in the CLASSPATH when you run in Eclipse but not when you run the executable JAR.  Add the Class-Path to your JAR manifest and put all the JARs with your executable JAR.  That should do it.

Comment: No, it really gets frozen without any exception. The classpath was my problem before (also an exception was occuring) but then I packed the jar with libraries, and the problem changed as described.

Comment: Areyou catching an exception?  I'll bet it is throwing one, you just don't know it.  Putting the JARs in the executable JAR does no good; you have to deploy them with the executable JAR.

Comment: yes, I'm catching and printing the exceptions and when the login fails, an exception is really thrown. But when the login is correct it really gets stuck without any exception. What do you mean with "to deploy"? There are 3 choices in Eclipse export to runnable jar: extract, package and copy required libraries. I tried all of them, but the result is the same.

Comment: I tried to kill the SQL Server and then the exception was thrown. The command DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password) after correct login really waits to infinity (or to SQL Server shutdown).

Comment: and this problem occurs only with remote connection. When I connect to a server on my computer, everything's ok. (From Eclipse, also the remote connection is ok)

Comment: Post more of your code.  Can't tell what you're doing from your statements.  The code will be definitive.

Comment: Thank you for your intention, but the Java update solved this (as @Mark Rotteveel posted)